# How can I read this barcode

Tags: python, image, image-processing, ocr, barcode-scanner

How can I read this barcode in python:

[image: bar code]

This is my code:

```
def do_one(image):
    print(image)
    image = KImage(image)
    l = time()
    def tick():
        nonlocal l
        n = time()
        t = n - l
        l = n
        return t

    union = set()
    first = []
    first_t = 0
    total_t = 0
    results = []
    for scalar in [0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 1, 1.5]:
        tick()
        if scalar != 1:
            image_scaled = scale_image(image.image, scalar=scalar).convert("L")
        else:
            image_scaled = image.image.convert("L")
        res = qrdecode(image_scaled)
        st = tick()
        union.update(res); total_t += st
        if res:
            first = res
            first_t = total_t
        for sharpness in [0.1, 0.5,1]:
            tick()
            image_scaled_sharp = sharpen(image_scaled, sharpness)
            res = qrdecode(image_scaled_sharp)
            t = tick()
            union.update(res); total_t += st + t
            if res:
                first = res
                first_t = total_t
        tick()
        image_scaled_autocontrast = autocontrast(image_scaled)
        res = qrdecode(image_scaled_autocontrast)
        t = tick()
        union.update(res); total_t += st + t
        if res:
            first = res
            first_t = total_t

    results.append({"file": image.filename,
                    "what": f"do-all-the-things",
                    "result": list(union),
                    "time": total_t})
    # queue.put(results)
    return results
```

I am able to read several bar codes but I have not been able to do this because of more improvements and changes that I make. Does anyone know how I can read this bar code?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the whole code including the `import`  statement so people can test solutions. Also, what exactly is preventing you from reading this one? Do you get an error or just no result?

Comment: Is that the original image, or did you process it already? There are some bars missing, I don’t think it is readable from this image. You need better quality input, either in gray-scale or with a higher pixel density.